# Google Map Marker as Reactjs Component

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, reactjs

[This stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23367489/google-map-api-marker-not-showing-with-reactjs) is answered by [@Omar Torres](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1759820/omar-torres) showing how to place a marker on a Google Map using Reactjs.

[Working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/torresomar/H6vhQ/)

I'd like to use an array to pull in multiple map markers, and I want the "marker" variable:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: this.mapCenterLatLng(), title: 'Hi', map: map});
```

To be a React Component so I can set a key and take advantage of the full performance of React's diff algo.

Here's my attempt, which isn't working:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
var ExampleMarker = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(this.props.lat, this.props.lon), title: this.props.mls, map: this.props.map});
        return (
            <div>{marker}</div>
        );
    }
});

var ExampleGoogleMap = React.createClass({  
    getDefaultProps: function () {
        return {
            initialZoom: 8,
            mapCenterLat: 20.7114,
            mapCenterLng: -157.7964,
        };
    },

    componentDidMount: function () {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: this.mapCenterLatLng(),
            zoom: this.props.initialZoom
        },
        map = new google.maps.Map(this.getDOMNode(), mapOptions);

        this.setMarkers(map);

        this.setState({map: map});
    },

    mapCenterLatLng: function () {
        var props = this.props;
        return new google.maps.LatLng(props.mapCenterLat, props.mapCenterLng);
    },

    setMarkers: function (map) {

        this.props.markers.forEach(function(marker) {
            <ExampleMarker mls={marker.mls_no} lat={marker.latitude} lon={listing.longitude} key={marker.mls_no} map={map} />;
        }.bind(this));
    },

    componentDidUpdate: function () {
        var map = this.state.map;

        map.panTo(this.mapCenterLatLng());
    },

    render: function () {
        var style = {
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%'
        };

        return (
            <div className='map' style={style}></div>
        );
    }
});

var data = [
    {
        'title' : "marker1",
        'latitude' : "21.883851754",
        'longitude' : "-159.465845879"
    },
    {
        'title' : "marker2",
        'latitude' : "22.1640990399",
        'longitude' : "-159.310355405"
    },
    {
        'title' : "marker3",
        'latitude' : "22.0855947129",
        'longitude' : "-159.344410728"
    }
];


React.renderComponent(
     <ExampleGoogleMap markers={data} />,$('body')[0]
);
```

Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure there is a way to diff **DOM elements of markers** with React as that is controlled by google's library.

With example from @Omar Tores, React is not aware of the marker DOM elements, all it knows is the `div` element rendered in the `render` method of `ExampleGoogleMap`. So the markers are not re-rendered at each re-render cycle. You have to handle the updates to markers in the `componentDidUpdate` method yourself.

With your example, you are creating `ExampleMarker`s in your `setMarkers` method which is called from `componentDidMount` method. Since these `ExampleMarker`s are not created in the `render` function, neither their `render` methods are executed 
nor they are going to be diff'ed at the subsequent renders of `ExampleGoogleMap`. Also wrapping the marker with a `div` element will not going to work.

All rendering logic of a marker is encapsulated within google library, therefore I think it not possible to diff it with Reacts algo unless google implements a react version of the library itself.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Thanks you @nilgun.

Answer (score 1):

solution: . check this  https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps and please React is very very fast give keys to components showing list/rows items of data to help react.

//check my code below

```js
showMapMarkers({markers}){
  ..use logic below 
}

class WeatherList extends Component{

renderWeather(cityData, i){
  const temps = cityData.list.map(weather => weather.main.temp);
  const pressures = cityData.list.map(weather => weather.main.pressure);
  const humidity = cityData.list.map(weather => weather.main.humidity);
  //distructuring
  // const lon = cityData.city.coord.lon;
  // const lat = cityData.city.coord.lat;
  const {lon, lat} = cityData.city.coord;
  return(
    <tr key={i}>
      <td><GoogleMap lon={lon} lat={lat} /></td>
      <td><Chart data={temps} color="orange" units="K"/></td>
      <td><Chart data={pressures} color="green" units="hPa"/></td>
      <td><Chart data={humidity} color="blue" units="%"/></td>
    </tr>
  );
}
  render(){
    return (
      <table className="table table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Temperature (K)</th>
            <th>Pressure (hPa)</th>
            <th>Humidity (%)</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {this.props.weather.map(this.renderWeather)}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}
```