# How to load google maps markers in a React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, react-google-maps

I've found this post here with a similar issue, but it didn't help.
*[Google Map Marker as Reactjs Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28470902/google-map-marker-as-reactjs-component)*

In my database I have some Latitude and Longitude values stored. I retrieve these values in a model to display some data for the user. I am sending these values to a simple Google Maps Component I created following this tutorial *https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#introduction*

The component receives "model" from "props", I get these values and set in two variables and try to send them to the google component.

The map simply does not load with these values I am sending. If I don't use "parseFloat" I get an error saying the values were not in a correct format.

```
import React from 'react'
import {withGoogleMap,
     withScriptjs,
     GoogleMap,
     Marker } from 'react-google-maps';
import { compose, withProps } from 'recompose'

const MyMapComponent = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap((props) =>
 <GoogleMap
  defaultZoom={8}
  defaultCenter={{lat:parseFloat(props.lat),lng:parseFloat(props.long)}}
 >
  {props.isMarkerShown && <Marker position={{lat:-18.245630,lng:-45.222387}} 
 />}
 </GoogleMap>
))

export default class extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
   isMarkerShown: false
 }
}
componentDidMount() {
 this.delayedShowMarker()
}
delayedShowMarker = () => {
 setTimeout(() => {
  this.setState({ isMarkerShown: true })
 }, 3000)
}
handleMarkerClick = () => {
  this.setState({ isMarkerShown: false })
  this.delayedShowMarker()
}
render() {
  let { model } = this.props;
  let lat = model.value.latitudeGeoreferencia
  let long = model.value.longitudeGeoreferencia
  return (
    <MyMapComponent
      isMarkerShown
      googleMapURL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?
      key=myKey.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places"
      loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
      containerElement={<div style={{ height: `400px` }} />}
      mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
      lat
      long
    />
  )
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't passing the props to `MyMapComponent`. If you just put the attribute name, it will receive true as the prop value. Try:

```
<MyMapComponent
    isMarkerShown={this.state.isMarkerShown}
    googleMapURL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?
    key=myKey.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places"
    loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
    containerElement={<div style={{ height: `400px` }} />}
    mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
    lat={lat}
    long={long}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked. Do you know if it is possible to send the markers values back to the previous component? I other words, if the user wants to save another location, I need to send those values back to the model, so I can send it to my controller.

Comment: Sure, you would need to pass a callback as a prop from your parent component, have a look at [this codepen](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/LzWZvb) and how the "Only show products in stock" checkbox interacts with the parent component. 

Alternatively you could consider using Redux, you would then 'connect' your two components. The example provided on the site loosely covers what you are looking for - https://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html

Comment: @ArthurMedeiros - did Matt's advice work for you? I'm wondering if it could be applied to my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49890542/how-to-add-map-markers-stored-in-a-json-feed-to-an-existing-react-google-map

Comment: @BaronGrivet yes, his advice worked for me. I read your question, and it seems like your are having an issue to load markers, right? I didn't mention it here, but in my case, I am using an axios call to retrieve the marker from a controller. This axios call was placed inside "componentDidMount". Does your fetch function do the same thing?  I understand your JSON gets updated somewhere, and then you want react to seet it has changed, I am right? If so,  have you tried using ComponentDidUpdate? But that won't be enough, it seems like you need something a loop that would keep listening to changes